How to derive Eq (1.34) based on a circuit as Eq (1.5) does in the book Neuronal Dynamics
In section 1.5 of text Neuronal Dynamics, there is an equation (1.34). I have difficulty understanding how this equation is derived. I can see that this equation looks very similar to equation (1.5) in section 1.3.1 of the same book. I understand the circuit in Fig. 1.6 and how Eq (1.5) is derived, so I tried to build up a connection between the two equations to help understand. But I cannot figure out a circuit like the one in Fig. 1.6 that corresponds to a concrete thing. For example, the $u(t)$ in Eq (1.5) is the membrane potential of a neuron, but I don't know what thing the threshold $\vartheta$ corresponds to that can help me derive Eq (1.34). Hope someone could please help me with it. Thanks.

Please include all the information necessary to answer your question in tbe post, like the equations you're talking about. Links to other sources are good to give credit and background but the question here must be self contained and not rely on people visiting an outside resource. We don't want questions to become unreadable when links invariably rot away.
